# SQL- Densidades de población de las provincias

Tags: sql

Podríais ayudarme con esta consulta de `SQL` que se me atraganta, gracias.

Para sacar la densidad de población,¿la consulta sería algo así?
tengo una tabla con:

- PROVINCIA
- POBLACIÓN
- SUPERFICIE

  `SELECT provincia, superficie/poblacion densidad FROM provincias;`

No se por qué me da un dato erróneo.

Comment: Que sql utilizas? MySql? Sql Server? ...?
Que tipo de dato son Población y superficie? INT?

Comment: Por favor, incluye la definición de la tabla para saber el tipo de dato de cada columna.  Un par de filas de muestra no estarían mal. Indica qué motor de bd usas. Todo esto lo añades editando tu pregunta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
SELECT provincia, (poblacion/superficie) AS densidad from provincias
```

**PD**: Ten en cuenta que los campos "superficie" y "población" deben ser tipo `double` para poder realizar operaciones matemáticas.

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es la densidad de población no deberías calcular superficie por personas, deberías hacer población/superficie, eso te dará un valor en función de la superficie que tengas a repartir, ¿estará ahí el error?.

Puedes encontrar más información mucho mejor explicada [aquí](https://es.wikihow.com/calcular-la-densidad-poblacional).